# HTML5 Tabular data align td content

Tags: html, html-table, column-width

I'm attempting to create tabular data in HTML5: I'm well versed in tables in (X)HTML and quite fan of the way to specify columns widths with `<colgroup> <col width=?>` but I've understood that using colgroups in html5 is obsolete. The way to go is using CSS. For small tables this is not a problem. My problem is that my tables are quite large and have over hundreds to rows. Specify a class or style for each `<td>` most will cause the size of the html code to explode and also could cause performance problems.

What is a proper way of efficiently specify column widths and textalignments on larger a tables in html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use styled `<col>` in a `<colgroup>` to specify widths. Style `<td>` and `<th>` for text alignment

Comment: Thanks. I had html4 style sizes here. But they should read <colgroup><col style='width:50px;'>...</colgroup>